# How to check if current route in Laravel Blade matches a pattern?

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm checking the routes inside my blade template, to add an active class to a specific `li` in my menu with this code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="{{ Request::is('*/sobre') || Request::is('*') ? "active" : "" }}">
        <a href="{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters()['domain'] . "/sobre" }}">Sobre o salão</a>
    </li>
    <li class="{{ Request::is('*/servicos') ? "active" : "" }}">
        <a href="{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters()['domain'] . "/servicos" }}">Serviços</a>
    </li>
    <li class="{{ Request::is('*/avaliacoes') ? "active" : "" }}">
        <a href="{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters()['domain'] . "/avaliacoes" }}">Avaliações</a>
    </li>
    <li class="{{ Request::is('*/galeria') ? "active" : "" }}">
        <a href="{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters()['domain'] . "/galeria" }}">Fotos</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And those are the routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{domain}', 'middleware'=>'salao'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Frontend\FrontendSalaoController@sobre');
    Route::get('sobre', 'Frontend\FrontendSalaoController@sobre');
    Route::get('servicos', 'Frontend\FrontendSalaoController@servicos');
    Route::get('avaliacoes', 'Frontend\FrontendSalaoController@avaliacoes');
    Route::get('galeria', 'Frontend\FrontendSalaoController@galeria');
});
```

When i access the route `http://website/x` or the route `http://website/x/sobre`, the active class is positioned correctly. But, if I access the `http://website/x/servicos` route, the class will be added in the first li and in the `servicos` li.

How can i handle this?

Answer (score 10):

`Request::is('*')` actually matches *everything* so the first item will always have the active class. Instead you should check for `'/'`:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('*/sobre') || Request::is('/') ? "active" : "" }}">
```

The `is` method even supports multiple parameters, of which only one has to match, so you can shorten it to this:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('*/sobre', '/') ? "active" : "" }}">
```

Comment: If you don't have a trailng `/` in your Urls you might have to check for `Request::is('')`. Checking for `''` worked while checking for `/` didn't work.